# PHP XML Get Node Values

Tags: php, xml, amazon-mws

I need to be able to take the information out of this XML file in order to display on the front end during the checkout process of my Magento site.  This file is returned to me from Amazon with the shipping information I need to show the user:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetFulfillmentPreviewResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentOutboundShipment/2010-10-01/">
  <GetFulfillmentPreviewResult>
    <FulfillmentPreviews>
      <member>
        <ShippingSpeedCategory>Standard</ShippingSpeedCategory>
        <IsFulfillable>true</IsFulfillable>
        <IsCODCapable>false</IsCODCapable>
        <EstimatedShippingWeight>
          <Unit>POUNDS</Unit>
          <Value>1</Value>
        </EstimatedShippingWeight>
        <EstimatedFees>
          <member>
            <Name>FBAPerUnitFulfillmentFee</Name>
            <Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Value>0.75</Value>
            </Amount>
          </member>
          <member>
            <Name>FBAPerOrderFulfillmentFee</Name>
            <Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Value>4.75</Value>
            </Amount>
          </member>
          <member>
            <Name>FBATransportationFee</Name>
            <Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Value>0.45</Value>
            </Amount>
          </member>
        </EstimatedFees>
        <FulfillmentPreviewShipments>
          <member>
            <EarliestShipDate>2016-07-28T07:00:00Z</EarliestShipDate>
            <LatestShipDate>2016-07-29T06:59:59Z</LatestShipDate>
            <EarliestArrivalDate>2016-08-02T07:00:00Z</EarliestArrivalDate>
            <LatestArrivalDate>2016-08-05T06:59:59Z</LatestArrivalDate>
            <FulfillmentPreviewItems>
              <member>
                <SellerSKU>BM-1100-14</SellerSKU>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId>BM-1100-14</SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId>
                <EstimatedShippingWeight>
                  <Unit>POUNDS</Unit>
                  <Value>0.119</Value>
                </EstimatedShippingWeight>
                <ShippingWeightCalculationMethod>Dimensional</ShippingWeightCalculationMethod>
              </member>
            </FulfillmentPreviewItems>
          </member>
        </FulfillmentPreviewShipments>
        <UnfulfillablePreviewItems/>
        <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
      </member>
      <member>
        <ShippingSpeedCategory>Priority</ShippingSpeedCategory>
        <IsFulfillable>true</IsFulfillable>
        <IsCODCapable>false</IsCODCapable>
        <EstimatedShippingWeight>
          <Unit>POUNDS</Unit>
          <Value>1</Value>
        </EstimatedShippingWeight>
        <EstimatedFees>
          <member>
            <Name>FBAPerUnitFulfillmentFee</Name>
            <Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Value>0.75</Value>
            </Amount>
          </member>
          <member>
            <Name>FBAPerOrderFulfillmentFee</Name>
            <Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Value>14.75</Value>
            </Amount>
          </member>
          <member>
            <Name>FBATransportationFee</Name>
            <Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Value>1.50</Value>
            </Amount>
          </member>
        </EstimatedFees>
        <FulfillmentPreviewShipments>
          <member>
            <EarliestShipDate>2016-07-29T00:00:00Z</EarliestShipDate>
            <LatestShipDate>2016-07-29T00:00:00Z</LatestShipDate>
            <EarliestArrivalDate>2016-07-29T07:00:00Z</EarliestArrivalDate>
            <LatestArrivalDate>2016-07-30T06:59:59Z</LatestArrivalDate>
            <FulfillmentPreviewItems>
              <member>
                <SellerSKU>BM-1100-14</SellerSKU>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId>BM-1100-14</SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId>
                <EstimatedShippingWeight>
                  <Unit>POUNDS</Unit>
                  <Value>0.119</Value>
                </EstimatedShippingWeight>
                <ShippingWeightCalculationMethod>Dimensional</ShippingWeightCalculationMethod>
              </member>
            </FulfillmentPreviewItems>
          </member>
        </FulfillmentPreviewShipments>
        <UnfulfillablePreviewItems/>
        <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
      </member>
      <member>
        <ShippingSpeedCategory>Expedited</ShippingSpeedCategory>
        <IsFulfillable>true</IsFulfillable>
        <IsCODCapable>false</IsCODCapable>
        <EstimatedShippingWeight>
          <Unit>POUNDS</Unit>
          <Value>1</Value>
        </EstimatedShippingWeight>
        <EstimatedFees>
          <member>
            <Name>FBAPerUnitFulfillmentFee</Name>
            <Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Value>0.75</Value>
            </Amount>
          </member>
          <member>
            <Name>FBAPerOrderFulfillmentFee</Name>
            <Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Value>7.75</Value>
            </Amount>
          </member>
          <member>
            <Name>FBATransportationFee</Name>
            <Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Value>0.55</Value>
            </Amount>
          </member>
        </EstimatedFees>
        <FulfillmentPreviewShipments>
          <member>
            <EarliestShipDate>2016-07-29T00:00:00Z</EarliestShipDate>
            <LatestShipDate>2016-07-29T00:00:00Z</LatestShipDate>
            <EarliestArrivalDate>2016-08-01T07:00:00Z</EarliestArrivalDate>
            <LatestArrivalDate>2016-08-02T06:59:59Z</LatestArrivalDate>
            <FulfillmentPreviewItems>
              <member>
                <SellerSKU>BM-1100-14</SellerSKU>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId>BM-1100-14</SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId>
                <EstimatedShippingWeight>
                  <Unit>POUNDS</Unit>
                  <Value>0.119</Value>
                </EstimatedShippingWeight>
                <ShippingWeightCalculationMethod>Dimensional</ShippingWeightCalculationMethod>
              </member>
            </FulfillmentPreviewItems>
          </member>
        </FulfillmentPreviewShipments>
        <UnfulfillablePreviewItems/>
        <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
      </member>
    </FulfillmentPreviews>
  </GetFulfillmentPreviewResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>eced620f-543d-4d45-9262-1ac49a638d37</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetFulfillmentPreviewResponse>
```

How can I properly read through this document and get the information I need?

Comment: php has a lot of libs for xml parsing. Google and find.

Comment: It's going to be easier and faster for people to help you out if you post some code of what have you tried to do and where are you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

[See this answer for a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553519/parsing-amazon-mws-scratchpad-response/30669821#30669821)

```
//convert an xml string into an array
function xml2array($xml){
    $xml = preg_replace('/(<\/?)\w+:([^>]*>)/', '$1$2', $xml); //get rid of namespaces
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    return json_decode(json_encode($xml),true); //use built-in stuff
}
```

and then

```
$array = xml2array($your_xml_text);
print_r($array);
```

Once the xml is parsed into an array you can easily get the data you want.